# Possible to setup a ftp proxy at home so i can work from coffee shops?

Tags: proxy

My company has firewall rules that only allow my home IP access to their servers.

Can i set up an ftp proxy at my house so i can ftp into the servers from other places? Is this sort of thing possible? if so, how? Sometimes i get sick of working from my home office =)

Thanks

Comment: Home internet connections are on dynamic IPs, except in rare circumstances and you're specifically charged for a fixed IP. Are you sure it's tied to your IP?

Comment: it is tied to my ip. when my ip changes i have to give my boss my new ip in order to get into the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is an SSH tunnel. However, FTP is not the most tunnel-friendly protocol (it is somewhat possible, [see wikipedia for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29)).

To forward a port from your laptop to your work computer (1.2.3.4) via your house computer (2.3.4.5), you can do something like:

```
ssh -L10099:1.2.3.4:99 2.3.4.5
```

Now accessing local port 10099 will connect you to your work computer port 99 (I do not remember if there are some settings to change in `ssh_config` or `sshd_config`).

If tunneling does not work, another possible option in Linux is to ssh to your home computer and download the files there, then you can mount the directory locally with `sshfs`. Just a bit better than double FTP (work->home->laptop).

Finally, you can set up a VPN between your laptop and house and have ad-hoc IP routing to your work computer.

Comment: im going to go with remote desktoping into my home computer and downloading the files. then using sshfs. thanks a lot